# MS Reporting Services mark as read checkbox/link

Tags: reporting-services

I have report with some messages, and I would like to know is there a way for RS to have checkbox or link which will, when clicked mark message as read, or in other words, inserts/updates isRead column for that id?

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it possible? Yes. Is it easy? Not a easy as most things in SSRS. Will it be elegant? Probably not.

You could create a check box icon which would link back to the report or some other action on the server. This would need to be set to handle a parameter indicating the checkbox clicked. Build a stored proc or other mechanism in the report to catch these clicks and make your column changes.

The biggest problem with this approach would be that, by default, the entire report would need to rerun and reload. You might be able to get something working that keep this smaller, but I'm not sure how.

My advice: don't do it. SSRS isn't designed to support this sort of interactivity with the data source. You'll be fighting against the tool. Look for another interface for this.